# How to use File environment variable in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I have a private key for deployment which I have set as a File Environment variable in the gitlab ci settings. However when I try and do

```
echo $VAR
```

the output is the entire contents of the key something like

```
----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY---
dfbvjladfbgvjksadbavkjabdfjnvkdjbnv;sdf98qw374yriuebglvkjsdfgydjkfvnldafkjbvgjkaldb
----END PRIVATE KEY---
```

I would like to have this key stored in a file and would like the **path to the file** as the environment variable `$VAR`. I am unsure of how to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you need a file, why not just cat it to a file in a CI job and save it as an artefact to be available to later jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a couple of mistakes with respect to using the Environment variables.

The environment variables when declared in settings need not be imported in the yaml files as variables.

**Mistake**

```
variables:
    VAR : $VAR
```

This leads to the contents of the file being exposed in the log which we dont want in this case.

**Correct Way:**

We can just use the key as is in the yaml with `$VAR` this should give a temporary path to the file where the key is stored.